# convert columns of text to rows in python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x

input text image

[image]

I am using the below code to convert the columns to rows in the text. 
My requirement is to find the count of each character in each column in the text

```
b=[''.join(i) for i in zip(*a2.split())]
print(b)
```

I am getting below input

```
['CCACTCGT', 'GTGGCCCC', 'AGCACTGC', 'CCTGCAGA', 'TTTAACCA', 'CGTACCTC', 'CACCCCCA', 'CGCCCCTT', 'GCTCCATG', 'CCAAAGGA', 'GCTCGCCT', 'ACTCACCC', 'ATCCTGGG', 'GGAACGCT', 'ACATCCTG', 'CGGCTTGC', 'TCAACCCG', 'TACGCGTT', 'GTCATCGT', 'ACAGAACC', 'CCCCCCTC', 'CACCCTGT', 'CACTTCCG', 'CGACTTCC', 'AGCCTCGA', 'AACCTGCA', 'ACTTCGTG', 'GCCTTCGT', 'CCTCGTCG', 'TTGCGGTC', 'CTGAGTGA', 'GCTCGGTG', 'GTACACGC', 'GCCTGCGT', 'CGCCAGCG', 'GGATCGTA', 'CAGGCGGG', 'ATACCGCG', 'CCTTCGTC', 'CCCCTGAC', 'CGTCCCGC', 'CGCTAGTC', 'CGGCGCGG', 'CACCCCCC', 'TGCGCGTC', 'GACTCCGC', 'CCATCCAC', 'AGTCTTCG', 'CGCTGCGC', 'AATCTCCC', 'CACCACCC', 'TTGCGCTA', 'TCGTGCGC', 'CTTGGAGA', 'CGTAGTCG', 'CTTGCGCC', 'CCTAGCGC', 'ATTGGCGC', 'CCTCGGCC', 'TACCGCCG', 'CGCTCCGC', 'TAGCCTGC', 'CCTATTCC', 'ACAACCCA', 'GTGCCGGC']
```

You can see the last 5 columns in the text are not coming in the list.
Iam not able to figure it out why this is happening.Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Also please suggest if there is any other way to achieve the same result.

Comment: The string `a2` is not in any `frame` or `list` form. a split will only split it into individual characters. First you need to have it as proper abstract datatype like `dataframe`, `list`, `dictionary` or something. How you see rows there is not clear in your question. Its just blurb of text

Comment: @AbhishekDujari, in this case `split` is splitting on the newline/whitespace characters.  It is `zip` that is causing the issue.  See @TadeuszSznuk's answer below.

Comment: ah I see. there is `\n` at the end. its the triple quotes that always leads me to assume the worst. hah silly me. apologies

Comment: @AbhishekDujari - anyway we can convert this text to data frame?

Comment: Ok I couldnt edit my comment but here is the full dataframe

    `data = str.splitlines(data)`
    `data_as_list = [ list(x) for x in data]`
    `df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_list)`

Answer (score 1):

`zip` returns as many tuples as there are items in the *shortest* iterable, so only full columns are returned. To get all columns you can use `zip_longest`, like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
b = [''.join(i) for i in zip_longest(*a2.split(), fillvalue='')]
```

Comment: @Tadeusz Sznuk - Anyway we can convert this text to data frame ?

Comment: Great answer by the way.

Comment: I converted text to list and then to dataframe.Iam getting the below output